# `eval { $constant_name }` gives the name, not the value

Tags: perl, constants, eval

I have defined several Perl constants like `use constant LVL_FATAL => 1;` (perl 5.18.2).
When trying to create a function that needs the name and the value of the constant, I tried:

```perl
my $level = eval { 'LVL_' . $_ };
```

When `$_` is `FATAL`, then `$level` contains `LVL_FATAL`, but not the value of `LVL_FATAL`.

I also tried the variants `eval { $level }`, `eval { ($level) }`, `eval { my x = $level }`, and `eval { print $level }`.
They all use `LVL_FATAL`.

However when I use `eval "$level"`, then I get `1`.
Also when i use `eval { LVL_FATAL }` I get `1`, too.

Can I use the block variant instead of the string variant for robustness and performance reasons?

### Remark

Remembering that Perl constants are basically functions, I tried `eval ${level}()`, but that did not work; `eval { $level->() }` seemed to do the job in the debugger, but when I used it in my program code, it did not work, however.

(When not using  `eval`, `LVL_FATAL->()` will give an error ("Undefined subroutine &main::1 ..."), but `LVL_FATAL()` is OK.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
my $level = eval { my $name = "LVL_$_"; __PACKAGE__->$name() };
```

According to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) :

> Constants belong to the package they are defined in. [...]
> Constants may be exported by modules, and
> may also be called as either class or instance methods, that is, as
> `Some::Package->CONSTANT` or as `$obj->CONSTANT` where `$obj` is an instance
> of `Some::Package`. Subclasses may define their own constants to
> override those in their base class.

Comment: `print eval { __PACKAGE__->$level }` works, but looks ugly.

Answer (score 3):

`eval BLOCK` and `eval EXPR` are very different.

`eval BLOCK` catches exceptions thrown by the code in the block. It is known as `try` in some other languages.

`eval EXPR` compiles and executes the string returned by `EXPR`. (Exceptions are also caught.)

You want the latter.

```
my $level = eval("LVL_$_");
die $@ if $@;
```

But since constants can be used as subs, you could also use

```
my $level = do { no strict qw( refs );  "LVL_$_"->() };
```

You could also call this "sub" as a method.

```
my $name = "LVL_$_";
my $level = __PACKAGE__->$name();
```

I prefer the second-last version because it makes it obvious that you are doing something weird and dangerous (and it doesn't pretend that a sub that isn't a method is a method).

Comment: It looks as if the shortest variant is `$level = eval { eval 'LVL_' . $_ } foreach ('FATAL')` (`foreach` added to define `$_`).

Comment: 1) That's actually lot longer than what I posted (you replaced `eval("LVL_$_")` with `eval { eval 'LVL_' . $_ }`), 2) it doesn't make any sense (the `eval BLOCK` does absolutely nothing but clobber `$@`), 3) it's very slow (compared to the solution I recommended), and 4) it hides errors if you don't follow up with `die $@ if $@;` (except you can't cause you clobbered `$@`). Yikes!